# How can I write from the ArrayList to file, each element from the ArraList in a new line?

Tags: java, file, arraylist

What I wanted to do is convert an ArrayList to file and after that, use the file line per line.

My code:

```
List<String> Inserts = new ArrayList<String>();
String FileToLoad = null;
.
.
.
.
FileToLoad = prpfile.properties();

System.out.println(FileToLoad);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(FileToLoad);
    for (String str : Inserts) {
        writer.write(str);
    }
    writer.close();

    String QueryNewData = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + FileToLoad + "' INTO TABLE companies  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (Name,Address,NumberDUG,post,status)";
    UpdateDatabase LoadNewData = new UpdateDatabase();
    LoadNewData.LoadQuery(QueryNewData);
```

Onces the code run, the file is created correctly but it's made the wholw ArrayLIst in one single line. How could inlude a new line for each element in the ArrayList?

Comment: Of course it does, why should it not? Please check the appropriate Java API, it's free. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(char[])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the obvious things that are wrong with your code:

- naming convention not followed
- stream not closed in finally {}
- ...

You must remember that a simple writer does not magically append line feeds, you could wrap it in a printwriter which has a println() much like `System.out` or you could do as the other answer suggest (i.e.) add a line feed manually.

However for cross-platform reasons I would suggest:

```
writer.write(str + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it's the best answer `writer.write(str + System.getProperty("line.separator"));` just one thing you forgot one bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `FileWriter` in a `BufferedWriter`. [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html). `FileWriter` has the `newLine()` method.

Other option is to write the new line using `System.lineSeparator()`, which is cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to use it simple way than others suggested, you can use printwriter as it have println() method which takes string as parameter.

```
 PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(FileToLoad);
 for(int index=0;index<Inserts.size();index++)
 {
     pw.println(arrayList.get(index));       
 }
 //pw.flush(); not needed since by default its enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CreateFileFromList {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("This is line 1.");
        list.add("This is line 2.");
        list.add("This is line 3.");
        File f = new File ("C:\\temp\\Sample.txt");
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        for(String s : list) {
            bw.write(s + System.getProperty("line.separator")); 
        }
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

New file Sample.txt will be created on c:\temp directory along with below contents:

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
```